# Pagination Links in Python and Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a flask app and I've managed to get some kind of pagination working.

```
@projects.route('/projects/<int:project_id>')
def projects_pages(project_id):
    ROWS_PER_PAGE = 2
    page = request.args.get('page', project_id, type=int)

    projects = db_session.query(Projects, Workspaces, Categories, Servers).filter(Projects.workspace_id==Workspaces.workspaces_id, Projects.category_id==Categories.categories_id, Projects.projects_release==Servers.server_id).limit(ROWS_PER_PAGE).offset((page - 1) * ROWS_PER_PAGE).all()

    res = [
        {
            "id": project.Projects.projects_id,
            "name": project.Projects.projects_name,
            "description": project.Projects.projects_description,
            "category_id": project.Projects.category_id,
            "category_name": project.Categories.categories_name,
            "workspace_id": project.Projects.workspace_id,
            "visibility_level": project.Projects.visibility_level,
            "slug": project.Projects.projects_slug,
            "workspace_name": project.Workspaces.workspaces_name,
            "release_id": project.Projects.projects_release,
            "release_name": project.Servers.server_name
        } for project in projects]

    project_output =  {"count": len(res), "projects": res}
    return render_template('projects.html', title='Projects', project=project_output)
```

The thing I'm stuck on now is how do I build the links to the pagination in Jinja?

Comment: you could try this extension, [flask-paginate](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/)